# Возникает сразу несколько ошибок при попытке скомпилировать проект

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

при попытке скомпилировать проект в Unity 2020 возникает сразу несколько ошибок:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

также когда я запускаю проект для тестирования, вижу следующую картину:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть, я немогу нажать ни на одну кнопку, и вообще ничего не хочет двигаться и происходить - я это вижу по времени  в право верхнем углу - оно застыло... если я нажимаю на кнопки вверху - на паузу например, то кадр просто сменяется на другой... я это вижу по времени, например если было 10:39:00 то я нажал на паузу, и стало 10:39:05, потом еще раз и стало 10:39:07... В чем проблема?(

Comment: Самая верхняя ошибка - про то, что не подключена библиотека. Вы этот проект сами писали или откуда-то скачали? А то может с проектом шёл какой-то мануал, который вы забыли прочитать?

Comment: нет, проект мой...

Comment: ага! я понял в чем проблема:) у меня в проекте есть ARReferenceImageLibrary...

Comment: эмм, не знаете в чем причина - подключаю ARReferenceImageLibrary, и проект не хочет компилироваться?

Comment: эммм, вы так мало привели подробностей о том, как подключали ARReferenceImageLibrary что я могу дать только очевидный ответ "значит, как-то криво подключали". Вы хотя бы переведите что написано в первых двух ошибках: там сказано, что не получилось сгенерировать базу изображений, проблема в ARCore - может наведёт на какие-то мысли о том, что сделали не так. Либо подробно рассказывайте, как подключали.

Comment: я просто зашел в Assets, затем кликнул правой кнопкой мыши, дальше выбрал XR, затем ReferenceImageLibrary, затем добавил изображение в нее, которое недавно импортировал в мой проект... - это все...